# htaccess: generates error if dot(.) exists in query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’ve written .htaccess file as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

#open the product details page with the Product Number with PN prefix 
RewriteRule ^((products/|product/|)PN[0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?pno=$1 


#open the product search page for a particular category 
RewriteRule ^((bat|ref|acc)[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search.php?cat=$1 [NC]

#open the product search page for a particular category 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.,]+)/?$ search.php?search =$1  [NC]

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=4]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscor} ^Yes$
```

1. It couldn't accept if there is dot(.) in the query string value. Now, it is solved, but can't accept its previous rule.
2. Furthermore, I want it to rewrite the "URL/product.php?pno=PN123" properly if the URL "URL/products/PN123" or "URL/product/PN123" is given. Please note that it can redirect correctly if "URL/PN123" is given correctly with proper CSS. AND "URL/product/PN123" can also retrieve the data but can't show CSS prperly.

Comment: What sends `Object not found?` The search.php query?

Comment: Can you not just add a dot into the character class? `^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/?$`

Comment: @Michael, I added a dot, but it didn't work. In this case, it would go blank page instead of error message.

Comment: Turn on `display_errors` in PHP if you have a blank page.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  You may have a syntax error or unfiltered SQL query or something...

Comment: Yes, display_errors is ON. It doesn't generate PHP error in that case. It just hangs on the blank page.

Comment: It sounds to me as if this is some interaction with other `.htaccess` rewrite rules.  Can you please edit your Q and add the remaining rewrite directives that you are using.

Comment: If you accept a dot in the url, `search.php` will also match the rewriteRule, causing an infinite loop. Prevent this using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1`

Comment: @Gerben: Yes, it works for me if there is only rule what written on my question. But, if I add other rules, it can't redirect correctly after adding this RewriteCond. Though, other rules would work fine without this RewriteCond.

Comment: @wasimchy That's what happens if you don't post your entire htaccess. We don't have crystal balls here :-)

Comment: @Gerben: I've edited the question and added other rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your corrected/updated .htaccess, however it would have been better if had written more about your actual requirements:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#open the product details page with the Product Number with PN prefix 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((products/|product/|)PN[0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?pno=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#open the product search page for a particular category 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((bat|ref|acc)[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search.php?cat=$1  [L,NC,QSA]

#open the product search page for a particular category 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.,]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=4,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscor} ^Yes$
```

About your css, js, image file: Make sure your path to css, js etc start with a slash `/` and not a relative one.

Comment: Thanks. Probably, your answer will solve my problem. But now, only problem is: anything with URL (for example: "URL/aboutus.html") redirect to the search page with "aboutus.html in search box.

Comment: When you say `URL/aboutus.html` Is there a physical file in `/URL/about.html` path? If YES then it should not redirect to search page since it also has `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line before which basically says apply next rewriterule IF it is not a physical file.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few bugs in your regexps.  Load up [this checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules/#9261963) on your site if you want to play with these.

- The pattern `^((products/|product/|)PN[0-9-]+)/` does not match "URL/products/PN123" or "URL/product/PN123" or "URL/PN123" and return the PN123 because of the embedded match string and the trailing slash.  You can hide the product(s)/ and make the trailing / optional as below.
- I don't like using the ! prefix in rule patterns, especially when using a grouped parts.  Too easy to shoot yourself in the foot.  I prefer a cond followed by a null rule or a negative lookahead.
- Fall-though match rules can trigger the postfix bug so again I avoid them.  The engine loops retrying .htaccess files (because they are evaluated in a "*Per Directory* context") 
  until no match so I find it just a LOT safer to always use the [L] flag
- Again because of this looping you need to assure that your rules will terminate and its better to do this in a simple transparent manner.  In this case you don't seem to want to
  rewrite URIs which map to real files so why not hoist the `-f` test to the top and all other rules can then assume that this condition is true.
- The two search rule mean that the cat=acc123 parameter is used if the request is for /acc123/ etc and search= otherwise.  Is this what you want?
- You need to include the QSA flag *unless* you want to ignore any existing parameters.
- The environment variable USCOR (I stick to uppercase) becomes REDIRECT_USCOR on the next pass so this is what you test for.  I assume that a rule follows this last cond

Putting these all together gets:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The rewrite engine loops in a Per Dir context. We don't remap real files so:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       -f
RewriteRule ^                         -                           [L]

# Open the product details page with the Product Number with PN prefix 
RewriteRule ^(?:products?)?(PN\d+)/?$ product.php?pno=$1          [L,NC,QSA]

# Open the product search page for a particular category
RewriteRule ^((?:bat|ref|acc)[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search.php?cat=$1  [L,NC,QSA]

#open the product search page for a particular category 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.,]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1           [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule \.(?!(php|html)$)               -                 [S=4,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)$  $1-$2-$3-$4-$5    [E=USCOR:Yes, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)$        $1-$2-$3-$4       [E=USCOR:Yes, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)$              $1-$2-$3          [E=USCOR:Yes, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_(.*)$                    $1-$2             [E=USCOR:Yes, L]
```

I am not sure what you want to do with %{ENV:REDIRECT_USCOR} now without the additional rules and logic, though it will be available to the script as `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_USCOR']`.